# Cannot install lmxl on last AWS EB plateform version

Tags: amazon-web-services, gcc, lxml

When trying to install lxml on the last ElastikBeantalk/Python plateform (64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.6 running Python 3.4) , I get a strange gcc compilation error :

```
building 'lxml.etree' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/lxml
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip-build-2phsf7cy/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:364460: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
warnings.warn(msg)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected EC2 server was a t1.micro (selected by default) .. Too old and small...